# Tikz arrow compiles to wrong location when used in the align environment

Tags: align, tikz-arrows

Can you help me prevent my arrow from showing up on the wrong page.  I have a tikz arrow in an `align` environment and for some reason, the arrow shows up on the following page and not in its intended location.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}

\subsection{Test 2}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{Solution}
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} & = \Phi_{k}x_{k} + w_{k}   && w_{k}\sim N(0,Q_{k})\\
z_{k+1} & = H_{k+1}x_{k+1} + v_{k+1}   && v_{k}\sim N(0,R_{k})\\
\bar{x}_{0}, & ~P_{0}\nonumber\\
\intertext{Parameter Values and Initial conditions:}
\Phi_{k} & = e^{-1}, \quad Q_{k} = q = 2, \quad P_{0}=2, \quad \bar{x_{0}} = 0 \nonumber\\
R_{k} & = r = 4,  \quad H_{k}=h=1\nonumber\\
\hat{x}^{-}_{k+1} & = \tikz[baseline]{\node[draw=myblueii,fill=mybluei!20,anchor=base,
                                            ellipse,inner xsep=-1pt,inner ysep=0pt]
  (d13) {$e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k}$}}\nonumber\\[1ex]
\hat{x}_{k+1} & = \hat{x}^{-}_{k+1} + K_{k+1}(z_{k+1}-e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k})\nonumber\\
\Aboxed{\hat{x}_{k+1} & = e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k} + K_{k+1}(z_{k+1}-e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k})}\nonumber\\
\intertext{where}
\Aboxed{K_{k+1} & = P_{k+1}H'_{k+1}R^{-1}_{k+1} = P_{k+1}\cdot\frac14}\nonumber\\
\intertext{where}
P_{k+1} & = \left[ P_{k+1}^{-^{-1}}+H'_{k+1}R^{-1}_{k+1}H_{k+1}\right]^{-1}\nonumber\\
P_{k+1} & = \left[\left( \Phi_{k}P_{k}\Phi'_{k}\right)+\frac14 \right]^{-1}\nonumber\\
\Aboxed{P_{k+1} & = \left[ \left(e^{-1}P_{k}e^{-1}\right)^{-1} + \frac14 \right]^{-1}}\nonumber\\
K_{k+1} & = \frac14\left[ \frac{e^{-2}}{P_{k}} + \frac14\right]^{-1}\nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[myblueii,thick,->] (d13) to [in=90,out=235] +(240:.55cm) node[anchor=north,text = black,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{flalign*}
\textbf{(a)}    &&  P(1)        & = 3.1479              &&  \\
                &&  K(1)        & = 0.786986            &&  \\
                &&  \hat{x}(1)  & = 0 + 0.786986(1.5-0) &&  \\
                &&              & = 1.1805              &&  \\[1ex]
\end{flalign*}
\qed

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to draw the arrow on the same page. Once TeX ships a page out, it is done with that page. It cannot go back and add anything. So the code for the arrow is too late - the page it belongs on has already gone.

Comment: But I did, it is on the 6th line of the `align` equation.

Comment: That's the node. I thought the arrow was the issue. That's not added until after the end of the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX ships out a page and is done with it forever. It won't go back and change it. So, if the node is on page 1 and the arrow isn't added until page 2, the arrow cannot get onto page 1. No way, no how.

If you try putting the `tikzpicture` before `align` as it is, you get errors. But if you use `tikzmark` (rather than just loading it), it'll work. You may get an error on the first run, but it'll work on the second. (For a way around this, see the documentation.)

[image: arrow from mark]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}

\subsection{Test 2}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{Solution}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[myblueii,thick,->] (pic cs:markme) to [in=90,out=235] +(240:.55cm) node[anchor=north,text = black,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} & = \Phi_{k}x_{k} + w_{k}   && w_{k}\sim N(0,Q_{k})\\
z_{k+1} & = H_{k+1}x_{k+1} + v_{k+1}   && v_{k}\sim N(0,R_{k})\\
\bar{x}_{0}, & ~P_{0}\nonumber\\
\intertext{Parameter Values and Initial conditions:}
\Phi_{k} & = e^{-1}, \quad Q_{k} = q = 2, \quad P_{0}=2, \quad \bar{x_{0}} = 0 \nonumber\\
R_{k} & = r = 4,  \quad H_{k}=h=1\nonumber\\
\hat{x}^{-}_{k+1} & = \tikzmark{markme}\tikz[baseline]{\node[draw=myblueii,fill=mybluei!20,anchor=base,
                                            ellipse,inner xsep=-1pt,inner ysep=0pt]
  (d13) {$e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k}$}}\nonumber\\[1ex]
\hat{x}_{k+1} & = \hat{x}^{-}_{k+1} + K_{k+1}(z_{k+1}-e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k})\nonumber\\
\Aboxed{\hat{x}_{k+1} & = e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k} + K_{k+1}(z_{k+1}-e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k})}\nonumber\\
\intertext{where}
\Aboxed{K_{k+1} & = P_{k+1}H'_{k+1}R^{-1}_{k+1} = P_{k+1}\cdot\frac14}\nonumber\\
\intertext{where}
P_{k+1} & = \left[ P_{k+1}^{-^{-1}}+H'_{k+1}R^{-1}_{k+1}H_{k+1}\right]^{-1}\nonumber\\
P_{k+1} & = \left[\left( \Phi_{k}P_{k}\Phi'_{k}\right)+\frac14 \right]^{-1}\nonumber\\
\Aboxed{P_{k+1} & = \left[ \left(e^{-1}P_{k}e^{-1}\right)^{-1} + \frac14 \right]^{-1}}\nonumber\\
K_{k+1} & = \frac14\left[ \frac{e^{-2}}{P_{k}} + \frac14\right]^{-1}\nonumber
\end{align}

\begin{flalign*}
\textbf{(a)}    &&  P(1)        & = 3.1479              &&  \\
                &&  K(1)        & = 0.786986            &&  \\
                &&  \hat{x}(1)  & = 0 + 0.786986(1.5-0) &&  \\
                &&              & = 1.1805              &&  \\[1ex]
\end{flalign*}
\qed

\end{document}
```